# Is "async/await" required in this sample code?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Windows Forms Application in C# to scan beacons using BLE. I'm using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement/cs/Scenario1_Watcher.xaml.cs) code as a guide. However I don't really understand why the event handlers (OnAdvertisementReceived, OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped) are async. Do I also need to make these event handlers async in my application? I'm not using WPF. If they need to be async, is that okay if I use await Task.Run and call the method to update the list on my form?

Here are the relevant methods from the external web site:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Invoked as an event handler when an advertisement is received. 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="watcher">Instance of watcher that triggered the event.</param> 
/// <param name="eventArgs">Event data containing information about the advertisement event.</param> 
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) 
{ 
    // We can obtain various information about the advertisement we just received by accessing  
    // the properties of the EventArgs class 


    // The timestamp of the event 
    DateTimeOffset timestamp = eventArgs.Timestamp; 


    // The type of advertisement 
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementType advertisementType = eventArgs.AdvertisementType; 


    // The received signal strength indicator (RSSI) 
    Int16 rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm; 


    // The local name of the advertising device contained within the payload, if any 
    string localName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName; 


    // Check if there are any manufacturer-specific sections. 
    // If there is, print the raw data of the first manufacturer section (if there are multiple). 
    string manufacturerDataString = ""; 
    var manufacturerSections = eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData; 
    if (manufacturerSections.Count > 0) 
    { 
        // Only print the first one of the list 
        var manufacturerData = manufacturerSections[0]; 
        var data = new byte[manufacturerData.Data.Length]; 
        using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(manufacturerData.Data)) 
        { 
            reader.ReadBytes(data); 
        } 
        // Print the company ID + the raw data in hex format 
        manufacturerDataString = string.Format("0x{0}: {1}", 
            manufacturerData.CompanyId.ToString("X"), 
            BitConverter.ToString(data)); 
    } 


    // Serialize UI update to the main UI thread 
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
    { 
        // Display these information on the list 
        ReceivedAdvertisementListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("[{0}]: type={1}, rssi={2}, name={3}, manufacturerData=[{4}]", 
            timestamp.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff"), 
            advertisementType.ToString(), 
            rssi.ToString(), 
            localName, 
            manufacturerDataString)); 
    }); 
} 


/// <summary> 
/// Invoked as an event handler when the watcher is stopped or aborted. 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="watcher">Instance of watcher that triggered the event.</param> 
/// <param name="eventArgs">Event data containing information about why the watcher stopped or aborted.</param> 
private async void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs) 
{ 
    // Notify the user that the watcher was stopped 
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
    { 
        rootPage.NotifyUser(string.Format("Watcher stopped or aborted: {0}", eventArgs.Error.ToString()), NotifyType.StatusMessage); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I also need to make these event handlers async in my application?

Probably not, but it depends on which GUI API you're using and how "correct" you want the code to be. :)

Let's address the original code example you're referencing first…

The first thing to notice is that an exception in the delegate invoked by `RunAsync()` is almost certainly not going to happen. The only difference in behavior for this particular example between using `async` and not is when an exception occurs, so if you're sure one won't, you don't need `async`.

Note that even if you do use `async`, using `async void` as in the event handlers here doesn't *handle* an exception per se. As a `void` method, these methods don't have a mechanism to relay an unhandled exception, so if an exception occurs in the method (e.g. by an `await` statement unpacking an exception that occurred in the asynchronous operation being awaited), that will still crash the process. But at least it does so right away, which is better than having it happen at some random time in the future.

From a practical point of view, the code in the original example gains only a bit from using `await`. If an exception occurs, the main difference is that it's detected, and causes the process to crash, immediately. Without `async`/`await`, the exception will still eventually crash the process, but not until the unawaited task object is garbage-collected and the finalizer runs (thus allowing the fact that the exception was unobserved to be detected).

All that said, if you really want to be safe, you might want to anticipate the possibility of exceptions.

In the `RunAsync()` method, this deals with exceptions the way actual `Task` objects would, which is to say that if an unhandled exception occurs in the task, and it remains unobserved until the task object is garbage-collected, the process will throw an exception at that time (i.e. when the object is collected).

By using `await`, you can observe and handle any such exception. E.g. by wrapping the call in `try`/`catch`. Of course, you would want to make sure to follow the usual best practices for handling exceptions, such as only handling exceptions you expect to occur and know that you can safely recover from.

If there are no such exceptions, it's still useful to use `async`/`await`, to ensure that any *unexpected* exception causes the process to crash. Not that having a process crash is ever a great thing, but it's usually better than just ignoring an exception and continuing on as if nothing happened. Using `async`/`await` can help ensure the crash happens right away, instead of relying on the timing of the garbage collector.

Note that this is particular to `RunAsync()` in Winrt, and `InvokeAsync()` in WPF. Winforms has a similar `BeginInvoke()` method that doesn't work the same way, at least in typical "fire-and-forget" usage. It allows the user to ignore exceptions if they occur and are unhandled (i.e. it displays a dialog giving the user the choice of continuing or terminating the process, rather than just automatically terminating). This is true even if you wrap the asynchronous operation with `TaskFactory.FromAsync()`.

To further confuse things, while WPF will crash the process if you `await` the exception-causing task in an `async void` method, it will *not* in the other scenarios (i.e. `await` an `async Task` method, or just not `await` at all). In WPF, the unobserved exception isn't treated the same as `Task` unobserved exceptions, the way it is in Winrt.

Anyway…

Other than the benefit in exception handling, the `async` and `await` don't do anything useful in the code examples. Since those methods don't do anything else after the `await`, and since there is no `try`/`catch` around the `await`, using `await` doesn't accomplish anything useful. If you know for sure no exception will occur, you could omit the use of `async` and `await`.

In your own code, you can accomplish the same end result by simply omitting `async` and `await` from those event handler methods, just as the author of that example code could have, had they desired to (arguably for example code, it's more important to do things "by the book", even if it doesn't actually accomplish anything real in the specific code example, since it could be important in other scenarios).

> I'm not using WPF. If they need to be async, is that okay if I use await Task.Run and call the method to update the list on my form?

The rules for Winforms and WPF are very similar. In the referenced code example, the code is calling `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` for the same basic reason you would in your Winforms code call `Control.BeginInvoke()` (or the synchronous `Control.Invoke()` method). You won't be able to use `Task.Run()` to execute code that needs to update your UI. Instead, you will need to use `Control.BeginInvoke()` or `Control.Invoke()`, so that the code that updates the UI is executed in the UI thread where it's required to execute.

As with the referenced code example, as long as you don't need to execute any more code in the event handler after calling `BeginInvoke()`, you have no need to add any sort of continuation, whether via `async`/`await` or other means.

Note that Winforms is very much like WPF in another respect: unlike in the Winrt code that used in the example, but very much like WPF's `InvokeAsync()`, an exception that occurs during a call to `BeginInvoke()` will be ignored if unhandled. So you can "safely" omit the use of `async` and `await` in Winforms programs as well, in this particular context.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I will be using Control.BeginInvoke to update the form.

Comment: One more question. If the UI and the BLE code runs on the same thread (I instantiate the BLE class in the form's class), does using BeginInvoke actually make any sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Where you create the BLE class doesn't necessarily tell you where the code executes. You can create the object in the UI thread, but still see the code (some or all) execute in another thread. The BLE API itself is inherently asynchronous and lends itself strongly to use of `async` and `await`. The event handlers are always executed in a non-UI thread, and so accessing the UI from the handlers will always require use of `BeginInvoke()` or similar. But for code you know _for sure_ executes in the UI thread, no...`BeginInvoke()` is usually not indicated.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Are you sure `async`/`await` isn't important here? I haven't tried it, but I would expect `Dispatcher.RunAsync` to swallow exceptions from its delegate if not `await`ed.

Comment: @StephenCleary: thanks, it seems I overlooked the slightly different behavior in Winrt vs WPF. `RunAsync()` behaves slightly differently from `InvokeAsync()`; I would say it does _not_ swallow exceptions. I.e. if not awaited, one gets an unhandled exception when the task is finalized. This doesn't happen in WPF. I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, I tried accessing the UI elements from the BLE event handlers and I got an exception. By using Control.BeginInvoke, I no longer get an exception. Thank you again!!

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Just one further observation: in the original code, the exception is not ignored; the `async void` method will raise it directly on its context (in this case, a thread pool context). This will cause an application crash.

Comment: @Stephen: ah, I see what you mean. I wrote my test code wrong, forgetting that the anonymous `async` method I invoked was inferred to return `Task` instead of `void`. You're of course correct that an `async void` method will crash the process if an unhandled exception is raised in the method. I find it interesting (and a little surprising) that while failing to await the call results in an unobserved exception that will crash the process, awaiting the call in an `async Task` method and ignoring the exception from _that_ `Task` object does not. What makes the exception observed in that case?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Well, it's like this (long story)... As of 4.5, unobserved Task exceptions no longer crash the app by default. So, ignoring a faulted Task is now the appropriate way to "fire and forget". `async void` treats exceptions in a special manner: they are re-raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the `async void` method. This sounds really weird, but makes sense if you only use `async void` as an async event handler: exceptions escaping an async event handler have the same behavior as exceptions escaping a sync event handler.

Comment: So, for an event raised on the thread pool (like this one), an exception escaping an `async void` handler will crash, just like an exception escaping a synchronous handler. Similarly, for a UI event, an exception escaping an `async void` handler will trigger `Application.OnException` (or whatever) for that UI framework, just like an exception escaping a synchronous handler.

Comment: @Stephen: so I did miss that in 4.5, unobserved Task exceptions no longer crash the process; that explains the WPF behavior I saw. But now I'm confused about my test app; in my Winrt (Store) app to test these scenarios, if I don't await the `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` task that throws an exception, when GC happens and finalizers are run, the process crashes. This is a Store app targeting Windows 8.1. Did Microsoft not make the same change to Winrt as they did to .NET in 4.5? Are they just going out of their way to make things confusing for people trying to target multiple "Windows" platforms?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I'm not sure why that would be happening. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with WinStore apps to say. I do find it surprising, though; WinRT apps *should* be running on a .NET 4.5 core.